# Javascript Iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

How can i make that iframe will load when i click on that image ?
I mean it will not load when the page load , only load when open it and close/stop load when close .
Here are code that i use .
Can some one help ?

```
<style type="text/css">
#gb{
position:fixed;
top:50px;
z-index:+1000;
}
* html #gb{position:relative;}
.gbtab{
height:100px;
width:30px;
float:left;
cursor:pointer;
background:url('http://i.imgur.com/YZMJf.png') no-repeat;
}
.gbcontent{
float:left;
border:2px solid #A5BD51;
background:#F5F5F5;
padding:10px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showHideGB(){
var gb = document.getElementById("gb");
var w = gb.offsetWidth;
gb.opened ? moveGB(0, 30-w) : moveGB(20-w, 0);
gb.opened = !gb.opened;
}
function moveGB(x0, xf){
var gb = document.getElementById("gb");
var dx = Math.abs(x0-xf) > 10 ? 5 : 1;
var dir = xf>x0 ? 1 : -1;
var x = x0 + dx * dir;
gb.style.right = x.toString() + "px";
if(x0!=xf){setTimeout("moveGB("+x+", "+xf+")", 10);}
}
</script>
<div id="gb">
<div class="gbtab" onclick="showHideGB()"> </div>
<div class="gbcontent">

<iframe src="http://yahoo.com"></iframe>
<br/>

<div style="text-align:right">
<a href="javascript:showHideGB()">
[close]
</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var gb = document.getElementById("gb");
gb.style.right = (30-gb.offsetWidth).toString() + "px";
</script>
```

This code will load the iframe when page load.

Comment: What's the problem? What doesn't work?

Comment: Do you not indent your code? Hard to read.

Comment: it working but i wan to change the iframe will load only when i click that image .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't set the iframe src directly in html. Do it inside the click handler function.

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe id="myifm"></iframe>

<script>
function loadIframecontent() {
  document.getElementById("myifm").setAttribute("src","http://www.yahoo.com");
}
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="loadIFrameContent();">Load Iframe Content</a>
```

Comment: can you help about the close part?

Comment: if you want to stop load, just `document.getElementById("myifm").removeNode();`